# Arduino-Arduino RF Communication, key needs to be pressed several times

Tags: arduino, rf, communication, delay

I'm communicating two Arduino i.e. Arduio UNO as sender & Arduino Mega as receiver via RF-433 MHz transiver module. Communication is sort of working but there is one problem. If I want to send a message, say, a number or character, I have to send that number or character multiple times using Arduino serial monitor. In other words, I have to press that key and send several times before the receiver is able to receive the message and act accordingly.

Question: **What do I need to do so my receiver gets the message in only one key press?**

My codes:

Transmitter code:

```
/* Bomb Displacing and Disposing Robot
Transmitter Code (Arduino UNO)  */

#include <VirtualWire.h>
int wrongSignal = 8;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  vw_setup(2400);
  vw_set_tx_pin(7);
  pinMode(wrongSignal,OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
 if(Serial.available())
{ 
  char c= Serial.read();

  if(c == '8')              //To move foreward
  {
    vw_send((uint8_t *)c, 1);    //send one bit i.e. 8
  }
  else if(c=='4')                //To move left
  {
    vw_send((uint8_t *)c, 1);    //send one bit i.e. 4
  }
  else if (c=='6')                //To move right
  {
  vw_send((uint8_t *)c, 1);        //send only one bit i.e. 6
  }
  else if(c=='2')                  // To move reverse
  {
  vw_send((uint8_t *)c, 1);        // send only one bit i.e. 2
  }
 else if(c=='5')                  // To stop
  {
  vw_send((uint8_t *)c, 1);        // send only one bit i.e. 5
  }

  else if(c=='0')                  // To stop
  {
  vw_send((uint8_t *)c, 1);        // send only one bit i.e. 5
  }
       Serial.println(c);
}
      else
            digitalWrite(wrongSignal, HIGH);

}
```

Receiver code:

```
//Receiver Code (Arduino Mega ADK 2560)


#include <VirtualWire.h>
// extra pins --------------------------------      
const int wrongSignal = 8;      // for indication that user sending invalid command
const int enablePin = 12;       // enable of the ICs used in circuit
//---------------------------------------------

// base controling pins -------------------

    // Front Left motor M1
    const int frontLeft1 = 30;
    const int frontLeft2 = 31;

    // Front Right motor M2
    const int frontRight1 = 32;
    const int frontRight2 = 33;

    //Back Left motor M3
    const int backLeft1 = 34;
    const int backLeft2 = 35;

    //Back Right motor M4    
    const int backRight1 = 36;
    const int backRight2 = 37;
//------------------------------------------

void setup() {

  //Extra pins
  pinMode(enablePin, OUTPUT);   // initialize the enable pin as an output
  pinMode(wrongSignal, OUTPUT);   //initialize wrongSignal pin as output pin

  // for Motor drive IC pins
  pinMode(frontLeft1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(frontLeft2, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(frontRight1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(frontRight2, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(backLeft1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(backLeft2, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(backRight1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(backRight2, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(enablePin, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);   // initialize serial communications:
   vw_setup(2400);      // baud rate is 2400
   vw_set_rx_pin(7);    // Receiver pin is pin 7
   vw_rx_start();        // start receiving
}
void loop()
{

  uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;
  uint8_t buf[buflen];

  if(vw_get_message(buf, &buflen))
  {

    for (int i = 0; i < buflen; i++)
    {
      if (buf[i] == '8')                  // move forward, all motors uni-direction
      { 
        digitalWrite(frontLeft1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(frontLeft2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(frontRight1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(frontRight2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backLeft1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(backLeft2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backRight1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(backRight2, LOW);
        }  

        else if (buf[i] == '4')              // move left, M1 >, M4 <
        {
        digitalWrite(frontLeft1, HIGH);    //M1
        digitalWrite(frontLeft2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(frontRight1, LOW);     //M2
        digitalWrite(frontRight2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backLeft1, LOW);      //M3
        digitalWrite(backLeft2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backRight1, LOW);      //M4
        digitalWrite(backRight2, HIGH);
      }

  // If the input is '0', turn off the ledPin i.e. send a low signal

  else if (buf[i] == '6')                // move right, M2>, M3<
  {
        digitalWrite(frontLeft1, LOW);      //M1
        digitalWrite(frontLeft2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(frontRight1, HIGH);      //M2
        digitalWrite(frontRight2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backLeft1, LOW);      //M3
        digitalWrite(backLeft2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(backRight1, LOW);      //M4
        digitalWrite(backRight2, LOW);
  }

    else if (buf[i] == '2')                // reverse
    {
        digitalWrite(frontLeft1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(frontLeft2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(frontRight1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(frontRight2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(backLeft1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backLeft2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(backRight1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backRight2, HIGH);
  }    

    else if (buf[i] == '5')                  // all motors stop
    {
        digitalWrite(frontLeft1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(frontLeft2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(frontRight1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(frontRight2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backLeft1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backLeft2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backRight1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backRight2, LOW);
  }        

    else if (buf[i] == '0')                  // all motors stop
    {
        digitalWrite(frontLeft1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(frontLeft2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(frontRight1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(frontRight2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backLeft1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backLeft2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backRight1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backRight2, LOW);
  }        
       else
          digitalWrite(wrongSignal, HIGH);



  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, your receiver may be missing some of the packets transmitted. Maybe the transmitter and reciever are too far apart or the antennaes are bad.

Another common reason for loosing packets is bad programming on the receiver. For example, your receiver may be in a delay() call when the packet arrives and loose it. But I cannot identify such problems in your code, as you're always checking if packets have arrived. In any case, to eliminate that possibility you can remove the transmitter and receiver modules (if that's possible in your setup) and place a wire between TX and RX of transmitter and receiver, respectively. Also, connect the grounds of both boards together. Then see if you still loose packets in the process. See [this link](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=124659.0) for more info on the process.

To try and find RF transmission problems (without proffessional gear), you can load the programs below in the transmitter and reciever boards, respectively, and see if there are packets being loss. The transmitter will send a sequence integers. You just have to check if they make their way to the receiver in sequence.

Test program for the transmitter:

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);   // Debugging only
    Serial.println("setup");
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);     

    // Initialise the IO and ISR
    //vw_set_ptt_inverted(true); // Required for DR3100
    vw_set_tx_pin(2);
    vw_setup(2000);  // Bits per sec
}

uint8_t buf[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;

int counter = 0;

void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(13, true); // Flash a light to show transmitting
    buf[0] = counter / 256;
    buf[1] = counter % 256;
    vw_send(buf, 2);
    vw_wait_tx(); // Wait until the whole message is gone
    counter++;
    digitalWrite(13, false);
    delay(100);
}
```

Test program for the receiver:

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Debugging only
  Serial.println("setup");
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);     
  // Initialise the IO and ISR
  //vw_set_ptt_inverted(true); // Required for DR3100
  vw_set_rx_pin(2);
  vw_setup(2000);    // Bits per sec

  vw_rx_start();       // Start the receiver PLL running
}

void loop()
{
  uint8_t buf[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
  uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;

  if (vw_get_message(buf, &buflen)) // Non-blocking
  {
    digitalWrite(13, true); // Flash a light to show received good message
    // Message with a good checksum received, dump it.
    Serial.print("Got: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < buflen; i++)
    {
      Serial.print(buf[i], HEX);
      Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.println("");        
    digitalWrite(13, false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've come across this problem before. It was a case of not sending a long enough preamble of 1s and 0s before the "real" data is transmitted. RF comms devices like this need to send a preamble to allow the receiving hardware to lock-on to the transmission. It's the RX data slicer (following the RF receiver) that needs to be dragged and aligned to the demodulator output before it can work correctly - this is for FM type transmission and reception.

For AM, there is a similar situation - the receiver's AGC circuit will be scratching around in the noise until a proper transmission is sent - the AGC takes time to acquire the correct settings and avoid being triggered by noise.

The preamble length should be several milli seconds but check the data sheet. Here's my interpretation of what happens on an FM system: -

[image]

To the left of the picture nothing is being transmitted and the receiver is randomly trying to lock-into noise (red curve). The blue line is an average of the red line - both signals feed a voltage comparator. Once a real data transmission is being sent, the averager begins alignment and after e few bits of preamble, it is aligned and genuine bits start popping out from the data slicer's output. An MCU connected to the data slicer output has to recognize preamble first, then, when the payload data arrives it can see it isn't preamble because it will have a different format (two stop bits is common to use the language of a UART).

This is just a suggestion based on my experiences.

Comment: Cool! But is there a way to increase the transmission preamble with VirtualWire and thus solve the OP's problem?

Comment: @Ricardo I have no idea - I don't even know if this is the problem - we need the OP to start giving more detail.